# set autocomplete attribute to off in Angular 5 Application

Tags: html, angular, autocomplete, angular5

I want to set autocomplete attribute to off for all the input elements in Angular 5 application.

for one input element, I am doing it like this :

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" autocomplete="off"style="max-width: 170px;">
```

I want to achieve this for all the input elements. Is there any way I can do this globally ?

Comment: There is no way I know of to set this globally.  You might be able to create your own Angular component, that acts as a wrapper for the input, and then turn autocomplete off inside that.  As long as you always use your custom component, the autocomplete will be off.

Comment: I think as we can achieve this in JS, we can achieve this in Angular as well.

Comment: Raviani I agree; how do you do it in JavaScript?

Comment: @Jerry : In a globle JS file you can have this code $(" input").attr("autocomplete", "off");

Comment: To me, that looks like JQuery; not vanilla JavaScript.  If I try to run that command using JavaScript: https://plnkr.co/edit/tn1SjV41Xj88FbfXMekt?p=preview then I get a `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error.

Comment: But JQuery is Javascript library itself.

Comment: Raviani Correct!  So, open up the JQuery code and figure out how it does it and then convert it to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input element inside form than you could use:

`<form action="/" method="get" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>`

Syntax:

```
<form autocomplete="on|off">
```

Comment: No, I am not using form.